# BASEMAP and GDAL data loading error

Tags: python, gdal, basemap

BASEMAP

```
activities_and_attractions = pd.read_csv("data/activities_and_attractions.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1")

mp = Basemap(resolution='l', llcrnrlon=-150, llcrnrlat=45, urcrnrlon=-110, urcrnrlat=60)

mp.scatter(activities_and_attractions.X, activities_and_attractions.Y, marker='o', color='b', label='Activities and '
                                                                                                    'Attractions')
mp.readshapefile("data/road_features_inventory", "Road Features Inventory")

activities_and_attractions = pd.read_csv("data/activities_and_attractions.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1")

plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

gives error

```
/anaconda/bin/python /Users/Chu/Documents/dssg/dssg.py
/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py:3222: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The ishold function was deprecated in version 2.0.
  b = ax.ishold()
/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py:3231: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: axes.hold is deprecated.
    See the API Changes document (http://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html)
    for more details.
  ax.hold(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chu/Documents/dssg/dssg.py", line 19, in <module>
    mp.readshapefile("data/road_features_inventory", "Road Features Inventory")
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 2146, in readshapefile
    for shprec in shf.shapeRecords():
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/shapefile.py", line 543, in shapeRecords
    for rec in zip(self.shapes(), self.records())]
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/shapefile.py", line 515, in records
    r = self.__record()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/shapefile.py", line 491, in __record
    value = u(value)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/shapefile.py", line 58, in u
    return v.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 6: invalid start byte
```

and GDAL

```
os.chdir('data/')
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

data_source = driver.Open('roda_features_inventory.shp', 0)
layer = data_source.GetLayer()
n = layer.GetFeatureCount()
print(n)
```

gives error

```
/anaconda/bin/python /Users/Chu/Documents/dssg/dssg.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chu/Documents/dssg/dssg.py", line 32, in <module>
    layer = data_source.GetLayer()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayer'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: In the GDAL case you use a relative path for shape file and it is not in your actual directory. Change your cwd to the directory of the shape file or change the path in driver.Open. You can check data_source before open to avoid error message.

Comment: In the pandas case you have non UTF-8 character in your input file. Use e.g. iconv to convert to UTF-8.